# Android Image Picker Select multiple images from gallery with a maximum limit of 5

Tags: android, limit, image-gallery, multipleselection

I have an app where the user needs to be able to choose multiple pictures to send them somewhere. However, they can only send five images at a time. I need to be able to limit the number of images that they can pick from the gallery through the Image Picker.

To put it in a single sentence: **I want to limit the number of images/photos that the user can select in the default image selector from the gallery**.

Here is the code that I am using for my image picker:

```
Intent chooseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
chooseIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
startActivityForResult(chooseIntent, 2);
```

It already keeps track of how many images are selected at the top by default:

[image]

Is there a way to set a maximum limit? Like to have a user only be able to select up to 5 images.

Comment: I just did some testing to different devices, sad to say not compatible to samsung s7 devices, but it works on google nexus 6P. So it means, that this code will only work to few devices.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> It already keeps track of how many images are selected at the top by default:

On that particular device, perhaps. Please understand that there are thousands of Android device models, and manufacturers set up their own UI to replace that of stock apps. Do not assume that all devices will show a count in the action bar.

> Is there a way to set a maximum limit? Like to have a user only be able to select up to 5 images.

Not via `ACTION_PICK`. `ACTION_PICK` is not documented to support `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` at all, and so there may be devices that do not allow for multiple selection for that `Intent`. Even on the `Intent` actions for which `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is part of the protocol (e.g., `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`), there are no extras for controlling the maximum count.

You are welcome to create your own image-selection UI, based on the results of querying `MediaStore`, and establish your own limits. There are also [several image picker libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/157), and one of those may already offer this feature.